# How to get data of user after authorization in flutter

Tags: flutter, authorization, bloc

I am struggling with bloc in flutter. My logic part is in Authorization bloc and UI is, Authorization screen, just calling this methods. I have authorization through phone number with Firebase.

Everything works fine and after validation I am getting a user response, access and refresh tokens. After that I need to push to another screen depending on this user response. If I already authorized then my profile data response will be filled and I'll just push it to home screen.

But when I am a new user, the user response data will be null so regarding to that I need to push to Profile screen, where I will fill my **first name, last name and email**. So how to check my data in UI screen?

Here is my code

**SIGN IN** method in Authorization bloc

```dart
Future<bool> signIn(String smsCode) async {
      dynamic userInfo;
      String firstName;
      String lastName;
      String email;

      bool result = true;
      AuthCredential authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: this._verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

      final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
      final FirebaseUser currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
      assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
      final String idToken = await currentUser.getIdToken(refresh: true);
      _api.validateIdToken(idToken).then((response) {
         final model = new CustomerModel.fromJson(response);
         String password = response["password"];
         _api.getAccessToken(_phoneNumber, password).then((dynamic response2) {
          _accessToken = response2["access_token"];
          _refreshToken = response2["refresh_token"];
        });
      });

      if(firstName ==null && lastName == null && email == null){
        return false;
      }
      return result;
  }
```

Calling that method in my **Authorization screen**

```dart
void _doLogin() {

    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());

    if (pinCode.length < 6) {
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          duration: Duration(seconds: 3),
          content: Text('Пожалуйста введите код'),
        ),
      );
    } else {       
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Авторизация...$pinCode",
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
            gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
            timeInSecForIos: 3,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 13.0
         );
          bloc.signIn(pinCode).then((hasProfile){
            print(hasProfile);
            if(hasProfile){
              Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfileData()));
            }else {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()));
            }
          });
    }
  }
```

As you see I call it like this `bloc.signIn(pinCode).then((hasProfile){...` but the condition after that doesn't work. So I think maybe I need to update state or use stream or sink.. I am just new in **bloc** that's why I am lost. Please guide me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about storing your data, or data management. One way is to pass down from widget to widget. [Pass down to widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Gc8.png)

Another way is to have a single place where you store and retrieve all your data. [Single source of truth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywlwV.png)

Those are the two ways. With the first method, one would use statefulWidgets together with setState. This way is not recommended if you have a large or scalable application.

With the second method, there are multiple ways of storing the data, such as redux, BLoC/Rx, Provider, or MobX. Flutter recommend doing it with the provider method. The docs is a great place which explains exactly how to do it in a very clear way: [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Let me know if you have any questions.